# Notation related question concerning matrices in additive category.

Tags: matrices, notation

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{(1)}$ $\text{Definition 1:}$ A $\textbf{product}$ in the category $\textbf{K}$ of a a family of objects $(A_i\mid i\in I)$ is an object $A$ together with a family 
$$(A \xrightarrow{\normalsize{\text{in}}_i} A_i\mid i\in I)$$ of morphisms (called $\textbf{projections}$) with the property that given any other object $C$ similarly equipped with an $\textit{I}-$indexed family $(f_i:C\to A_i)$ there exists a

[image]

unique morphism $f:C\to A$ such that ${\pi}_i\circ f=f_i$ for all $i$ in $I.$  We write $A=\prod_{i\in I}A_i,$ If $I=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we may write $A=A_1\times\ldots\times A_n.$

$\textbf{(2a)}$ $\textbf{Proposition 1:}$  Given a family $(A_i\mid i\in I$ of vector spaces, we define their $\textbf{product}$ to be the cartesian product $$\prod_{i\in I}=\{f\mid f:\to \cup_{i\in I} A_i\text{ and } f(i)\in A_i \text{ for each }i\}$$

equipped with the 'coordinatewise' addition and multiplication-by-a-scalar $$(f+f")(i)=f(i)+f'(i)\quad \text{ and } (\lambda \cdot f)(i)(i)=\lambda\cdot f(i)$$

for all $f,f'$ in $\prod_{i\in I}A_i,\lambda$ in $\textbf{R}$ and $i\in I.$  Then $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ together with the projections $$\pi_j:\prod_{i\in I}A_i\to A_i:f\mapsto f(j)$$

is a product of $A_i)$ in the category $\textbf{Vect}$ in the sense of $\text{Definition 1:}$

Proof:  Just check that $p(c)(i)=p_i(c)$ does the trick in $\text{Definition 1:}.$

$\textbf{(2b)}$ $\textbf{Proposition 2:}$  Given a family $(A_i\mid i\in I)$ of vector spaces, we define their $\textbf{weak direct sum}$ to be

$$\coprod_{i\in I}A_i=\{f\mid f:I\to \cup_{i \in I}A_i;f(i)\in A_i \text{ 
for each }i;\text{ and supp}(f)\text{ is finite}\}$$

considered as a subspace of $\prod_{i\in I}A_i.$  Then $\coprod_{i\in I}A_i$ together with the injections

$\text{in}_j:A_j\to \coprod_{i\in I}A_i:a_j\mapsto$ the $f$ with $f(i)=0$  for $i\neq j,$ and with $f(j)=a_j$

is a coproduct of $(A_i)$ in the category $\textbf{Vect}.$

$\textbf{(3)}$....Thus $\textbf{R}^n$ is a product in $\textbf{Vect}$ via the projections $\pi_j:\textbf{R}^n\to \textbf{R},(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto x_j$ and is coproduct in $\textbf{Vect}$ via the injections $\text{in}_i:\textbf{R}\mapsto \textbf{R}^n, x\mapsto (0,\dots,x,0,\dots,0)$ (where $x$ occurs in the $i^\text{th}$ place).

As a prelude to the situation in arbitrary categories, let us observe that a linear map $f:\textbf{R}^3\to \textbf{R}^2$ corresponds to a $2\times 3$ $\textit{matrix}$ of linear maps $\textbf{R}\to \textbf{R}$

$$({f_i}^j)=\begin{pmatrix}{f_1}^1 & {f_2}^1 & {f_3}^1\\\ {f_1}^2 & {f_2}^2 & {f_3}^2\end{pmatrix}$$

as follows. Because $\textbf{R}^3=\textbf{R}+\textbf{R}+\textbf{R},$ $f$ corresponds to

$$\begin{pmatrix}f_1, & f_2, & f_3\end{pmatrix}$$

$(3)$ where $f_i=f\cdot \text{in}_i:\textbf{R}\to \textbf{R}^2.$  In turn, each $f_i$ corresponds to

$$\begin{pmatrix}{f_i}^1 \\\ {f_i}^2\end{pmatrix}$$

$(4)$ where ${f_i}^j=\pi_j\cdot f_i:\textbf{R}\to \textbf{R},$ because $\textbf{R}^2=\textbf{R}\times \textbf{R}.$  Thus $f$ corresponds to the $2\times 3$ matrix $({f_i}^j)$

As an example, using the universal properties of >>>>

$f(x,y,z)=f_1(x)+f_2(y)+f_3(z)$

$=\begin{pmatrix}{f_1}^1(x) & {f_2}^1(y) & {f_3}^1(z)\\\ {f_1}^2(x) & {f_2}^2(y) & {f_3}^2(z)\end{pmatrix}$

$\textbf{(4)}$ $\textbf{Theorem:}$  Let $\textbf{K}$ be a category in which $A+A, A\times A$ exist for every object $A.$  Then the following two conditions are equivalent.

1. $\textbf{K}$ admits an $\textbf{Abm}-$ structure.
2. $\textbf{K}$ is pointed (via $0_\text{AB},$ say) and for all $A,$ the map $\Delta:A+A\to A\times A$ defined by $\pi_j \cdot \Delta \cdot \text{in}_i = \delta_{ij}$ where in the matrix formulation of $\textbf{(1)}$

$$\begin{equation}
\delta_{ij}=
    \begin{cases}
        \text{id}_A & \text{if } i=j\\
        0 & \text{if } i\neq j
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$

is an isomorphism.

Moreover, if either of these conditions are true, the $\textbf{Abm}-$structure on $\textbf{K}$ is unique.

Note that we have "$\Delta=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

In the formulas from $(3)$ and $(4)$ which are respectively $f_i=f\cdot \text{in}_i$ and ${f_i}^j=\pi_j\cdot f_i,$ the two rows and three columns for the matrix:  $$\begin{pmatrix}{f_1}^1 & {f_2}^1 & {f_3}^1\\\ {f_1}^2 & {f_2}^2 & {f_3}^2\end{pmatrix}$$ are:

$(a)$ $f_1=f\cdot \text{in}_1,$ for $j=1,2,3$ means:

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}{f_1}^1 & {f_2}^1 & {f_3}^1\\\ {f_1}^2 & {f_2}^2 & {f_3}^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} {f_1}^1 & {f_2}^1 & {f_3}^1\end{pmatrix}$

$(b)$ $f_2=f\cdot \text{in}_2$ for $j=1,2,3$ means:

$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}{f_1}^1 & {f_2}^1 & {f_3}^1\\\ {f_1}^2 & {f_2}^2 & {f_3}^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} {f_1}^2 & {f_2}^2 & {f_3}^2\end{pmatrix}$

$(c)$ ${f_i}^1=\pi_1\cdot f_i$ for $i=1,2$ means:

$\begin{pmatrix}{f_1}^1 & {f_2}^1 & {f_3}^1\\\ {f_1}^2 & {f_2}^2 & {f_3}^2\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1 \\\ 0\\\  0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}{f_1}^1 \\\ {f_1}^1\end{pmatrix}$

$(d)$ ${f_i}^2=\pi_2\cdot f_i$ for $i=1,2$ means:

$\begin{pmatrix}{f_1}^1 & {f_2}^1 & {f_3}^1\\\ {f_1}^2 & {f_2}^2 & {f_3}^2\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0 \\\ 1\\\  0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}{f_2}^1 \\\ {f_2}^2\end{pmatrix}$

$(e)$ ${f_i}^3=\pi_3\cdot f_i$ for $i=1,2$ means:

$\begin{pmatrix}{f_1}^1 & {f_2}^1 & {f_3}^1\\\ {f_1}^2 & {f_2}^2 & {f_3}^2\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0 \\\ 0\\\  1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}{f_3}^1 \\\ {f_3}^2\end{pmatrix}$

But when it says that $f$ correspond to the $2\times 3$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix}{f_1}^1 & {f_2}^1 & {f_3}^1\\\ {f_1}^2 & {f_2}^2 & {f_3}^2\end{pmatrix},$ does it mean that $f:(i,j)\mapsto {f_i}^j$

since seems that in the following formula: ${f_i}^j=\pi_j\cdot f\cdot \text{in}_i,$ $f$ is given in the form of a matrix, but $f$ is suppose to be a map $f:\textbf{R}^3\to \textbf{R}^2$ defined as: $f:(-)\mapsto (-)=\begin{pmatrix}{f_1}^1 & {f_2}^1 & {f_3}^1\\\ {f_1}^2 & {f_2}^2 & {f_3}^2\end{pmatrix},$  where $f:(-)\mapsto (-)$ would mean $f:(i,j)\mapsto ({f_i}^j)?$

Also, if I want to have the matrix:  $f(x,y,z)=f_1(x)+f_2(y)+f_3(z)$

$=\begin{pmatrix}{f_1}^1(x) & {f_2}^1(y) & {f_3}^1(z)\\\ {f_1}^2(x) & {f_2}^2(y) & {f_3}^2(z)\end{pmatrix},$ by using the formula:  ${f_i}^j=\pi_j\cdot f\cdot \text{in}_i$?  How would I go about doing this?  Later on for the Theorem in $(4)$, I have to learn to make use of $\pi_j \cdot \Delta \cdot \text{in}_i = \delta_{ij}$ where $\Delta$ is the identity matrix.

Thank you in advance

Comment: $f:(i,j)\to f^j_i$ does not make sense. $(i,j)$ is not an element of the domain of the function nor is $f^j_i$ an element of the codomain.

Comment: All the matrix representation means is that $f$ is the unique map satisfying $\pi_j\circ f\circ\mathrm{in}_i=f^j_i$ for all suitable $i,j$.

Comment: @FShrike how is $f$ defined?

Comment: .. as that unique map